# optimization of massive query

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have the following query, which is used to create a percentage of how far the users are with filling in their information. I store it as a view, but the query takes about 6 minutes to run for 1500 users. How can I speed up this query?

It will be used as a query that would be run once every day on a time when users are inactive. We are currently quickly expanding our userbase and I'm just worried it will go completely wrong with 15,000 users.

So please MySQL guru's, I beg for your help!

```
CREATE VIEW profile_check AS(
SELECT users.id, 
    FORMAT(( IF(
        COUNT(users.firstname)+ 
        COUNT(users.lastname)+ 
        COUNT(users.gender)+
        COUNT(users.country)+
        COUNT(users.address_one)+
        COUNT(users.city)+
        COUNT(users.zipcode)+
        COUNT(users.housenumber)+
        COUNT(users.phonenumber)+
        COUNT(users.educationlevel_id) = 10, 1, 0) +
    IF(
        COUNT(assesspassionresults.user_id) > 0, 1, 0) +
    IF(
        COUNT(assessmentcompetencyresults.user_id) > 0, 1, 0) +
    IF(
        COUNT(assessmentstrengthresults.user_id) > 0, 1, 0) +
    IF(
        SUM(CASE WHEN timelines.component_of = "employer" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0, 1, 0) +
    IF(
        SUM(CASE WHEN timelines.component_of = "individual" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0, 1, 0) +
    IF(
        COUNT(interests.user_id) > 0, 1, 0) +
    IF(
        COUNT(skills.user_id) > 0, 1, 0) +
    IF(
        COUNT(users_mediafiles.user_id) > 0, 1, 0) ) / 9 , 0) as profiel_check
FROM users
LEFT JOIN assesspassionresults
    ON users.id = assesspassionresults.user_id
LEFT JOIN assessmentcompetencyresults
    ON users.id = assessmentcompetencyresults.user_id
LEFT JOIN assessmentstrengthresults
    ON users.id = assessmentstrengthresults.user_id
LEFT JOIN timelines
    ON users.id = timelines.user_id
LEFT JOIN interests
    ON users.id = interests.user_id
LEFT JOIN skills
    ON users.id = skills.user_id
LEFT JOIN users_mediafiles
    ON users.id = users_mediafiles.user_id
GROUP BY users.id);
```

The EXPLAIN

[image]

Comment: To get a useful answer, you need to post a schema, and an EXPLAIN at the very least; a SQLFiddle would be even better.

Comment: Apart from the missing explain (and probably missing indexes): are you sure you are getting the correct results? Your query looks like it will not give you what I guess you want to get. Or rather: I guess your check will give you a value of 88,9% at any given time.

Comment: @NevilleK I added in the EXPLAIN, didnt know this existed.
@ Solar Im getting the expected results, if I run it for just one user.

Comment: Your explain says, as expected, that you are missing all indexes. Create indexes for all your tables for your column user_id.

Comment: @Solarflare Im sorry I have absolutely no idea what indexes are or how I should add them in my query.

Comment: Check [Create index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html). And as I said before, I guess your result might not be what you want to get. You should check that too.

Comment: An index is something you add to a **table**, not a query. And, sorry, but indexes are a basic feature in relational database design. It should be explained in the first chapters of any SQL book. In your case, you may want to find out about [foreign keys](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)—when you define them, MySQL creates the appropriate indexes automatically.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález im sorry Alvaro, I have never learned about query optimization or for that part table indexing. Does that mean if I just add in the indexes per table my problem should be fixed?

Comment: A table index is like a book index. If you want to know whether a history book talks about French Revolution you can spend 5 days reading the book or 1 minute checking the index. This is the same: if you look at your explain plan, MySQL reads 100% of the table rows—an index could eventually allow to read less rows.

Comment: @Solarflare Can you elaborate on why you think the results will not be the same as what I think the expected results will be like?

Answer (score 0):

As the MySQL guru's suggested, adding in indexes on all the user_id columns would fix my performance issue. And it did!

```
ALTER TABLE assesspassionresults ADD INDEX (user_id);
ALTER TABLE assessmentcompetencyresults ADD INDEX (user_id);
ALTER TABLE assessmentstrengthresults ADD INDEX (user_id);
ALTER TABLE timelines ADD INDEX (user_id);
ALTER TABLE skills ADD INDEX (user_id);
ALTER TABLE users_mediafiles ADD INDEX (user_id);
ALTER TABLE interests ADD INDEX (user_id);
```